# R Shiny, dashboardSidebar breaks graphs and tables width when toggling

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, dygraphs, shinydashboard

When toggling the dashboardSidebar menu, graphs and tables (made through R Shiny) do not adjust their width accordingly.

Here is an example with a standard graph and table. When initialising the app, the graph and table fill the screen correctly, but toggling the menu breaks the width of both elements.

How can this be fixed so their width are 100% at all times?

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(dygraphs)

ui <- dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(),

    dashboardSidebar(
        sidebarMenu(id = "menu_tabs",
            menuItem("Test", tabName = "page_1", icon = icon("table"), selected = TRUE)                
        )
    ),

    dashboardBody(    
        tabItems(      
            tabItem(tabName = "page_1",              
                fluidRow(
                    column(width = 12, offset = 0,
                        box(width = 12,
                            dygraphOutput("dy_plot", height = "310px")
                        )
                    )
                ),

                fluidRow(
                    column(width = 12, offset = 0,
                        box(width = 12,
                            dataTableOutput('mytable')
                        )
                    )
                )              
            )         
        )
    )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

    output$mytable = renderDataTable({
        mtcars
    },
    options = list(
        lengthMenu = c(30),
        pageLength = 30,
        searching = FALSE,
        paging = FALSE,
        ordering = FALSE,
        scrollX = TRUE))

    output$dy_plot <- renderDygraph({
        lungDeaths <- cbind(mdeaths, fdeaths)
        dygraph(lungDeaths)
    })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Much Credit goes to this answer [Shiny dashboard does not scale well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36655640/shiny-dashboard-does-not-scale-well) where you can force the resize

```
rm(list = ls())
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(dygraphs)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),

  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(id = "menu_tabs",menuItem("Test", tabName = "page_1", icon = icon("table"), selected = TRUE)                
    )
  ),

  dashboardBody(    
    tags$script('
      // Bind function to the toggle sidebar button
      $(".sidebar-toggle").on("click",function(){
        $(window).trigger("resize"); // Trigger resize event
      })'
    ),
    tabItems(      
      tabItem(tabName = "page_1",              
              fluidRow(
                column(width = 12, offset = 0,
                       box(width = 12,
                           dygraphOutput("dy_plot", width = "100%", height = "310px")
                       )
                )
              ),

              fluidRow(
                column(width = 12, offset = 0,
                       box(width = 12,
                           dataTableOutput('mytable')
                       )
                )
              )              
      )         
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  output$mytable = renderDataTable({
    mtcars
  },
  options = list(
    lengthMenu = c(30),
    pageLength = 30,
    searching = FALSE,
    paging = FALSE,
    ordering = FALSE,
    scrollX = TRUE))

  output$dy_plot <- renderDygraph({
    lungDeaths <- cbind(mdeaths, fdeaths)
    dygraph(lungDeaths)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Actually, this has been fixed in the latest release of shinydashboard. Just re-install it from CRAN:

```
install.packages("shinydashboard")
```